# Различия между '\n' и std::endl

Tags: c++

Есть такой код:

```
int main() 
{ 
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
}
```

Второй код:

```
int main() 
{ 
    cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

Я знаю, что `endl` делает перенос и очищает буфер (`flush`). Но почему-то не вижу разницы, что с `endl`, что с `\n`, результат один - отображается `Hello, world!`

Как переписать код так, чтобы увидеть разницу с `endl` и `\n`?

Answer (score 12):

Думаю, что проблема в буферизации вывода.

В C++ потоки ввода и вывода могут быть в одном из трёх состояний: небуферизирован (любой вывод сразу попадает в целевой файл/пайп/на консоль), буферизирован построчно (символы попадают в вывод после окончания каждой строки, исчерпания внутреннего буфера или закрытия потока), и полностью буферизован (символы попадают в вывод лишь после исчерпания внутреннего буфера или закрытия потока).

Майкрософтовская реализация стандартной библиотеки [никогда не делает построчную буферизацию](https://web.archive.org/web/20170329163751/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/642876/std-wcout-is-ten-times-slower-than-wprintf-performance-bug-in-c-library) (почитайте ответ от [Stephan T. Lavavej](https://twitter.com/stephantlavavej)), имплементации на линуксе обычно делают.

В [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25569849/276994) содержится цитата из стандарта (C11 7.21.3 §7):

> the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device

(это относится к чистому C). У C++ та же политика, согласно [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26976002/276994):

> [C++11 27.4.2 [narrow.stream.objects]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/narrow.stream.objects#3) : The object `cout` controls output to a stream buffer associated with the object `stdout`.

Это означает, что если вывод производится на консоль, а не в файл, то вы увидите всегда полную строчку после `\n`. А вот если вывод перенаправлен, то произойдёт буферизация.

Вот пример. Рассмотрим код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cout << "this is " << "\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    std::cout << "SPARTAAAA!!!111" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

в MSVC 2015. Если запустить программу обыкновенным образом, мы увидим сначала `this is`, и лишь через 10 секунд `SPARTA`. А если запустить программу так: `a.exe >x.txt`, и заглянуть через пару секунд после запуска в файл `x.txt`, то вы не увидите там ничего до окончания работы программы.

Если заменить `"\n"` на `std::endl`, вывод в файл работает так же, как и на консоль.

---

Обновление: в MSVC 2015 установить буферизацию `std::cout` можно вручную (идея с благодарностью <s>украдена</s> подсмотрена в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11392874/276994)):

```
std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);

char mybuf[1024];
std::cout.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(mybuf, 1024);

std::cout << "this is " << "\n";
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
std::cout << "SPARTAAAA!!!111" << std::endl;
return 0;
```

Этот код выводит текст только после `std::endl`.

Comment: А как насчет разницы \r\n и \n на unix и win платформах

Comment: @gecube: Это за рамками данного вопроса. `std::endl` равносильно `\n` + `flush()` на любой платформе ([пруф](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)), а превращение `\n` в `\r\n` происходит в глубине `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 2):

Выведи еще что-то, чтобы увидеть разницу

```
int main() 
{ 
     cout << "Hello, world1!" << endl;
     cout << "Hello, world2!" << endl;
}
```

Выведет:

```
Hello, world1!
Hello, world2!
```

Но

```
int main() 
{ 
     cout << "Hello, world1!";
     cout << "Hello, world2!";
}
```

Выведет:

```
Hello, world1!Hello, world2!
```

`endl` всегда `flush`ит поток, сбрасывая буфера. \n же просто пихает в поток символ начала новой строки. Разница еще в том, что \n быстрее

Comment: Извините, я не точно задал вопрос. Дополнил.

Comment: а ещё разница в том, что `\n` не очищает буфер, это может быть критично при использовании файлов или доступа из-вне без консоли (консоль сама всегда флаш делает).

Comment: Некоторые варианты системной библиотеки делают автоматически flush, некоторые нет.