# Отображает непонятные символы c++

Tags: c++, поиск

Пытаюсь сделать поиск участников из существующего файла, но отображает изначально непонятные цифры, в следствии чего как я подозреваю не дает выполнить поиск.

```
void find_note() { 
string find_surname;
ifstream file("out.txt");
string surname, name, patronymic;
string dob;
string strana, instrument, mesto;
getline(file, surname, ' ');
getline(file, name, ' ');
getline(file, patronymic, ' ');
getline(file, dob, ' ');
getline(file, strana, ' ');
getline(file, instrument, ' ');
getline(file, mesto, ' ');
cout << "Введите фамилию участника" << '/n';
(cin >> find_surname).get();
if (find_surname == surname) {
    cout << "Участник: " << surname << " " << "" << name << " " << "" << patronymic << " " << "| " << "Дата рождения:" << dob << " " << "| " << "Страна:" << strana << "| " << "Музыкальный инструмент:" << instrument << "| " << "Занятое место:" << mesto << "\n";
}
else cout << "Невозможно найти";
system("pause");
menu();}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если /n - это переход на новую строку, то лучше писать \n. А еще лучше std::endl.

Comment: Точненько, спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup std::endl - это не совсем эквивалент '\n'

Comment: @timbars Да, я знаю. Просто в данном случае особой разницы нет.

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup А почему `endl` лучше?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528675/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-n-%D0%B8-stdendl

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup В чем разница я знаю. Просто я обычно слышал противоположный совет: использовать `\n`, чтобы работало быстрее...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Согласен, если работать с файлами. Но когда просто вывод в консоль, то поторебность в очистке буфера возникает чаще. Так зачем писать cout << "text\n" << flush если endl сделает и перевод строки и очистит буфер? Если я ошибаюсь, буду рад послушать Вас (без шуток)